# Objective-C compiler flags

Tags: objective-c, gcc

When compiling Objective-C from the command line (gcc), what are some good flags to use? Many of the standard C flags (`-Wall`, `-ansi`, etc) don't play well with Objective-C.

I currently just use `-lobjc` and `-framework`with various frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Many of the standard C flags (-Wall, -ansi, etc) don't play well with Objective-C

`-Wall` works perfectly fine with Objective-C.

The thing to do is build an Objective-C file with Xcode and have a look at the build transcript.  I've just done that and here are some highlights:

`-x objective-c` I guess that means "compile as Objective-C", probably important

`-arch x86_64` build for a particular CPU architecture

`-std=gnu99` build for C99 + GNU extensions (actually surprised me, I thought Xcode used -std=c99).

`-isysroot ....` specifies the location of the SDK.

`-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` I am compiling for 10.6 and up

`-fobjc-gc-only` this file was intended to be used with garbage collection and won't work without it, so I compile for GC only.

`-Wall` the obvious.

If you are compiling from the command line, it's probably a good idea to set the option to treat warnings as errors.  I don't from within Xcode because the build results window remembers the uncleared warnings from previous builds.